# Class Cast exception for the Hadoop new API

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

i have trying  to cough up with some simple code using Map reduce framework. Previously I had implemented using mapred package and I was able to specify the input format class as KeyvalueTextInputFormat But in the new Api using mapreduce  this class is not present. I tried using the TextInputFormat.class but i still get the following exception

```
- job_local_0001
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
    at com.hp.hpl.mapReduceprocessing.MapReduceWrapper$HitFileProccesorMapper_internal.map(MapReduceWrapper.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:621)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:177)
```

here is a sample snippet of the code

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
         conf.set("key.value.separator.output.line", ",");    

        Job job = new Job(conf, "Result Aggregation");
        job.setJarByClass(ProcessInputFile.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        job.setMapperClass(MultithreadedMapper.class);
        MultithreadedMapper.setMapperClass(job, HitFileProccesorMapper_internal.class);
        MultithreadedMapper.setNumberOfThreads(job, 3);
        //job.setMapperClass(HitFileProccesorMapper_internal.class);
        job.setReducerClass(HitFileReducer_internal.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);



        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(inputFileofhits.getName()));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(ProcessInputFile.resultAggProps
                .getProperty("OUTPUT_DIRECTORY")));

        try {
            job.waitForCompletion(true);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Please do let me know what are the configuration changes to be made so that classcast exception can be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when there is a type mismatch in what MapReduce is trying to pass through as a key/value and what the Map or Reduce class is templated to have.

You say that you are using `KeyvalueTextInputFormat`, but in your code you are using [`TextInputFormat`](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r1.0.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/TextInputFormat.html). `TextInputFormat` delivers records as `<LongWritable, Text>` : "position, line".

I'm going to guess that the type of your Mapper is `<Text, Text, ?, ?>`. Therefore, MapReduce is trying to cast the `LongWritable` that `TextInputFormat` is giving it to a `Text`, and it can't, so it bombs out.

I suggest you either `KeyvalueTextInputFormat` or change the type of your mapper to `<LongWritable, Text, ?, ?>`.

Comment: Hi, Thaks for the reply.. But i have mentioned that I had used KeyValueTextInputFormat previously.. This class is not present in the new version of hadoop that I am using currently.. I have modified my Mapper to Longwritable for now.. but I am still curious how to avoid the class cast exception.. Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean you are still curious how to avoid it? To avoid it, you need to be sure that your `<A, B, C, D>` template type in the mapper matches up with the input format.