# Local spark installation not working as expected

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-dynamodb

I have installed `Hadoop-Spark` on my local machine. I tried to connect to `AWS S3` and was successful in doing that. I used `hadoop-aws-2.8.0.jar` for this purpose. However, I have been trying to connect to `DynamoDB` using EMR provided jar file `emr-ddb-hadoop.jar`. I have installed all the AWS dependencies and are available locally. But, I have been getting the following exception continuously.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat
```

Here is my code snippet.

```
import sys
import os

if 'SPARK_HOME' not in os.environ:
  os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = "/usr/local/Cellar/spark"
  os.environ[
    'PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--jars /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.8.0/libexec/share/hadoop/tools/lib/emr-ddb-hadoop.jar,' \
                             '/home/aws-java-sdk/1.11.201/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.11.201.jar pyspark-shell'
  sys.path.append("/usr/local/Cellar/spark/python")
  sys.path.append("/usr/local/Cellar/spark/python")
  sys.path.append("/usr/local/Cellar/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip")

try:
  from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SQLContext, Row
  from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
  from pyspark.sql.window import Window
  import pyspark.sql.functions as func
  from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, lag, col, udf
  from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, FloatType, DoubleType, TimestampType, LongType
except ImportError as e:
  print("error importing spark modules", e)
  sys.exit(1)

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .master("spark://xxx.local:7077") \
    .appName("Sample") \
    .getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
conf = {"dynamodb.servicename": "dynamodb", \
    "dynamodb.input.tableName": "test-table", \
    "dynamodb.endpoint": "http://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/", \
    "dynamodb.regionid": "us-east-1", \
    "mapred.input.format.class": "org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat"}
dynamo_rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD('org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat',
    'org.apache.hadoop.io.Text',
    'org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBItemWritable',
    conf=conf)
dynamo_rdd.collect()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the newAPIHadoopRDD. Using the old api it works without issues.

Here is the working sample I followed,

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyze-your-data-on-amazon-dynamodb-with-apache-spark/

Comment: Tried this as well. Got the same error trace. Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeValue

Comment: Looks like your emr-ddb-hadoop.jar did not have those class file. I did checked in my jar and it is there.

Comment: I have downloaded it from maven repo. Any link to get your jar file?

Comment: Just checked my jar. It is importing com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeValue, but the jar file is 99kb so I assume it does not include AWS sdk.

Comment: I think that is the root cause. You might not have the aws sdk jars in classpath. I have that in ec2 and it has sdks in there by default.

Comment: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /mnt/var/lib/info/job-flow.json - Got this exception when I used the old api.Using the new API : java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934511/how-to-know-job-flow-id-other-cluster-parameters-in-script-running-via-script-r . This is what I see how you can all the info on job-flow.json. For the new api, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541345/class-cast-exception-for-the-hadoop-new-api . might help.

Comment: Looked at these. 2nd one dosent seem to work as I dont have control over the selection of Key Values from dynamodb. I followed this https://books.google.com/books?id=sNPvDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT567&lpg=PT567&dq=pyspark+dynamodb+samples&source=bl&ots=CtZP315FMe&sig=fjW_fqIoqdyD5Kk0Vzmjqoy0pyk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizz_-0o7nWAhXDSCYKHV_mAxsQ6AEIQjAF#v=onepage&q=pyspark%20dynamodb%20samples&f=false