# How to use pyspark to read a table with emr-dynamodb-connector

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-dynamodb

I want to use pyspark with [emr-dynamodb-connector](https://github.com/awslabs/emr-dynamodb-connector) to read an entire dynamodb table into an rdd or, preferably, a dataframe. My code follows.

`dynamodb.py`:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession(sc)

conf = {
    "dynamodb.servicename": "dynamodb",
    "dynamodb.input.tableName": "user_state_test",
    "dynamodb.output.tableName": "user_state_test",
    "dynamodb.endpoint": "https://dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
    "dynamodb.regionid": "us-west-2",
    "mapred.output.format.class": "org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.write.DynamoDBOutputFormat",
    "mapred.input.format.class": "org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat"
}

dynamoRDD = sc.hadoopRDD(
    inputFormatClass="org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat",
    keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.Text",
    valueClass="org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBItemWritable",
    conf=conf
)

count = dynamoRDD.count()
print(count)
```

In order to supply the emr connector, I built it using the maven build tool in accordance with the [awslabs instructions](https://github.com/awslabs/emr-dynamodb-connector#how-to-build):

1. Clone repo
2. `mvn clean install`.
3. The build results in a new jar in a target directory in the `emr-dynamodb-hadoop` dir of the repo, called `emr-dynamodb-hadoop-4.8.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`. I copied this jar into the repo my code is in and renamed it to `emr-dynamodb-hadoop.jar`.

I submit my spark job with the following command:

`spark-submit --master "local[4]" --jars /Users/vaerk/dev/myproject/emr-dynamodb-hadoop.jar dynamodb.py`

This code results in the following exception: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeValue`

My questions:

- Is the `AttributeValue` class contained in the `emr-dynamodb-hadoop.jar`? The answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46374369/local-spark-installation-not-working-as-expected) indicate that is should be.
- Does my spark submit correctly load that jar onto the classpath?
- and of course, what do I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: were you able to find anything on this ?

Comment: @vaer-k Are you able figure out how to read dynamodb from EMR pyspark code